# Dynamically Add and Remove Rows with Calculation Js

Tags: javascript

I would like a form where a user can add and remove rows.
Once the input has been added the respective fields will update by multiplying the qty * cost, as well as the bottom total field.

As I am new to js, I used the code from a pervious [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470273/perform-calculations-on-dynamically-added-rows)

However, the remove function is not working.

I have tried other solutions, however when a row gets removed the values don't update.

The ultimate goal is for a user to create a Quote with the tables and post it to a mysql database using ajax.

Therefore I changed the querySelectorAll to a class, for example class=qty, as more than one of the same id is not allowed.

Below is what I have so far.

The form:

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_service">

    <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
        <tbody>
        <tr id='row_0'>

            <td>
                <label>Service</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" 
                name="service[]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" class="qty" required="required" 
                name="qty[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" class="cost" required="required" 
                name="cost[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="total">Total</label>
                <input type="text" class="subtotal" 
                required="required" name="subtotal[]">
           </td>

            <!--<td>
                <a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>
            </td>-->
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>

        <input type="text" class="" id="grand_total">
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn- 
     info" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    /**$('table').on('click', 'tr a.remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });*/

    //submit data
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "push.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $('#add_service').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#add_service')[0].reset();
            }
        });
    });
});



function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 10) { 
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        row.id = 'row_' + rowCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
        }
        var listitems = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
        for (i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
            listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('" + 
        row.id + "')");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Maximum 10.");

    }
}


function calculate(elementID) {
    var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=qty]')[0].value;
    var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=cost]')[0].value;
    var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=subtotal]')[0];
    var myResult1 = myBox1 * myBox2;
    total.value = myResult1;

    grandtotal();
}

function grandtotal(){

    //calculation script
    var $form = $('#add_service'),
        $sumDisplay = $('#grand_total');

    var $summands = $form.find('.subtotal');
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function ()
    {
        var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });

    $sumDisplay.val(sum);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it is unclear how `addRow` is being called. I will assume that it is triggered by an event. You will need to uncomment the remove `td` and set the value of `onclick`:

```
<td>
    <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('dataTable', '0');">
</td>
```

and modify `addRow` as follows:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 10) { 
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        row.id = 'row_' + rowCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
        }
        var listitems = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
        for (i = 0; i < listitems.length - 1; i++) {
            listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('" + 
        row.id + "')");
        }
        listitems[listitems.length - 1].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + row.id + ")");
    } else {
        alert("Maximum 10.");

    }
}
```

This should result in your remove being generated. But we have a problem with ids, since if you remove the second row and there is a third row, then the way you specify the ids will result in duplicate ids. Therefore, if you remove an item, the ids of the subsequent rows will have to be decreased. Let's implement `removeRow`:

```
function removeRow(tableID, index) {
    //Removing the row
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    table.deleteRow(index);
    //Modifying the ids of subsequent rows
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = index; i < rowCount; i++) {
        table.rows[i].id = "row_" + i;
    }
    //Handling the counts
    grandtotal();
}
```

The code is untested, if you have any problem with it, I advise you to create a JSFiddle, so I will be able to easily test the code I have written.

Comment: Thank you. There is a bit of a bug. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swatch360/7co3mpbt/)

Comment: @swatch360 you did not add jQuery to your fiddle and therefore the error was that $ is not defined. Since all your Javascript is inside a document ready via jQuery, you will not experience the desired behavior. I have updated the JSFiddle with jquery involved. It seems to be working. If not, please specify what the bug you experience is.

Comment: The adding rows and calculation is working perfectly. As well as removing a row updates the total field. However, when I add a field again, it does not do the calculation. When I add a few more rows then the calculation seems to work by skipping a few rows.

Comment: It first creates duplicate id on the row, then it increments by 1.

Comment: @swatch360 if you give me the exact reproduction steps, then I will fix this problem for you. I am sure an index is mistaken somewhere and it is easy to fix this if I know how to reproduce. If you cannot provide the reproduction steps, then I am afraid I cannot help you now, as I will have very busy days.

Comment: On the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swatch360/7co3mpbt/). Add 2 new rows,  then delete last row. Then add a row again. There is a duplicate id for row_2.
This is causing the calculation not to work. It also deleting last row, not the row you select.

Comment: @swatch360 sorry for the delay, I was not able to get to answer you. I have updated the fiddle, fixing some bugs, please, test it and let me know if the answer is now bug free. https://jsfiddle.net/7co3mpbt/27/